# PHP: How to call php variable inside a css?

Tags: php, html, css, href

I'm building a photo portfolio, and I'm using PHP to read the images inside a folder, count them and then show them while applying a CSS. So each time I add  new files to the folder it just updates as I refresh the website.

**Problem:** I'm kinda new in PHP and I can't manage to add the `$image` array in the CSS href and style. Also not perfect in English sorry about that, hope I made myself clear.

```
<!--this was the old one for only a few images added 1 by 1, just the last serve as example -->
<a class="item" href="assets/img/portfolio/item-8.jpg">
    <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <div class="item-cover" style="background-image: url(assets/img/portfolio/item-8.jpg)"></div>
</a>

<!--created a new folder for images and trying it dynamic from here -->
<?php
    $files = glob("img/*.*");
    for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
        $image = $files[$i];
        $supported_file = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if(in_array($ext, $supported_file)) { ?>

            <a class="item" href="<?php echo $image; ?> "> <!--not working -->
                <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <div class="item-cover" style="background-image: <!-- got to add the array here like that? --> $image"></div>
            </a>

        <?php
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
?>
```

So it counts the images, and add them (I can tell by the number of divs it creates) as black since I don't know how to echo them.

Comment: What HTML is currently produced by this code: `<a class="item" href="<?php echo $image; ?> ">`?

Comment: a link is not supposed to show an image, img yes, what is it that's not working ? I guess you mean the path to the image ?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware it does the work but shows all in black, not the pictures. all well formated and positioned but not the pictures. and if i just echo them not using the css it shows the pictures, so assuming that the php part is well done.

Comment: What I am getting at is that the URL might be wrong. A path in the OS is not always the same as an URL of a web resource. And of course G-Cyr is right that the <a> is not the same as the <img> tag, so it won't show an image to start with, in the piece of code followed by `<!--not working -->`. The `<div>` tag could work if the URL is correct.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware hum ok, as i said im kinda new in this. gonna change it ill post a feedback. thanks.